# Copy an element class to another

Tags: jquery

I have following HTML structure. Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Click on any `.edit` class in any `.item` in the `.wrap` div, and display the `.list` div.
2. Select an item in `.list` div, copy the class of the `<i>` inside the selected div.
3. Add the copied class to the `<i>` which is is in the same class where the `.edit` link was clicked.

**Problem:**

When I click on the item in the `.list` div, I can find the selected item class, but I am unable to figure on how to find the class in which the edit link was clicked.

**Here's HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">
         <div class="icon1"><i class="default"></i>Default</div>
         <div class="edit">Change</div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
         <div class="icon2"><i class="default"></i>Default</div>
         <div class="edit">Change</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li> <i class="class1"></i>New 1</li>
        <li> <i class="class2"></i>New 2</li>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

So, In the above example, when I click on the 'Change', I want to select an item from .list and then copy the class in that item (eg. class1) and replace that with the  class .default.

**Here's jQuery:**

```
$('.edit').click(function(e){ 
      $('.list').css({display: 'block'});       
});

$('.list ul li').click(function() {
    $('.list ul li').removeAttr('class');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    var new_class = $(this).children('i').attr('class');
    //alert(new_class);
});
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/hfgsJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use a global variable to save the source of showing the list.

```
var source_element;

$('.edit').click(function(e){ 
    $('.list').css({display: 'block'});       
    source_element = $(this);
});

$('.list ul li').click(function() {
    $('.list ul li').removeAttr('class');
    $(this).addClass('selected');   
    new_class = $(this).children('i').attr('class');
    source_element.removeClass().addClass(new_class);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hfgsJ/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var $edits = $('.edit').click(function (e) {
    $('.list').css({
        display: 'block'
    });
    $edits.filter('.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});

var $lislis = $('.list ul li').click(function () {
    $lislis.removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    var new_class = $(this).children('i').attr('class');
    $edits.filter('.current').closest('.item').find('i').removeClass().addClass(new_class)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6nB8k/)

Answer (score 1):

the idea is to set a class for the selected item to be edited then navigate to that element using this class

```
$('.edit').click(function(e){ 
        $('.list').css({display: 'block'});
         $('.item').removeClass('selectedChange');
        $(this).parent().addClass('selectedChange');
        });
    $('.list ul li').click(function() {
        $('.list ul li').removeAttr('class');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        var new_class = $(this).children('i').attr('class');
        var toChangeItem = $('.item.selectedChange');
        toChangeItem.addClass(new_class);
        alert(new_class);
    });
```